# Как найти совпадение по значению в многомерном ассоциативном массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачи.
Как в пройтись в цикле по ассоциативному многомерному массиву и найти совпадения по `[fio]`?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [tab_num] => 22222
            [fio] => Том Харди
            [prof] => актер
            [start_work] => 2019-10-05
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [tab_num] => 31313
            [fio] => Том Харди
            [prof] => режиссер
            [start_work] => 2019-09-12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [tab_num] => 88888
            [fio] => Киллиан Мерфи
            [prof] => актер
            [start_work] => 2019-09-29
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [tab_num] => 81818
            [fio] => Киллиан Мерфи
            [prof] => режиссер
            [start_work] => 2019-09-10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно найти первый ключ массива с указанной фамилией,
то начиная с версии PHP >= 5.5.0 вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) следующим образом:

```
$key = array_search('Том Харди', array_column($test, 'fio'));
echo $key; // Выведет 0, первое совпадение
```

Где `$test` - это ваш массив.

Если нужно найти все ключи, то придется воспользоваться собственным кодом.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
  if ($test['fio'] === 'Том Харди') {
    $result[] = $key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отфильтровать, возьмите функцию фильтрации

```
$needle = "...";
$result = array_filter($data, function($v) use ($needle){ 
    return strcasecmp($v['fio'], $needle);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать простым перебором с созданием нового массива:

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $ids[$value['fio']][] = $value['id'];
    // Вместо $value['id'] можете поставить $key если вам нужны ключи массива.
    // Либо поставить $value['prof'], если вам нужен список профессий
}
```

Получится массив:

```
$ids = [
    'Том Харди' => [2, 11],
    'Киллиан Мерфи' => [8, 12]
];
```